# AngularJS: can I use filter, defined in another module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've an angular project, structured using by-module-type principle:

```
├── directives
├── services
├── filters
│   └── filters.js
└── states
    └── home
        ├── home.html
        └── home.module.js
```

I've created a custom filter in filters.js

```
import angular from "angular";

export default angular.module("app.filters", [])
    .filter("removeStartingWithDollar", function(items) {
        var filteredItems = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if (!item.startsWith('$')) { filteredItems.push(item);  }
        });
        return filteredItems;
    });
```

I want to use this `removeStartingWithDollar` filter in my home.html template. How do I inject it as a dependency and should I do that at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inject the `app.filters` module in anywhere you need to use any provider of it.

```
angular.module("MySecondModule", [app.filters])
```

Comment: I got a down vote for my answer. I'm sure he can't explain it ;)

Comment: The down vote may be because you are injecting a variable rather than a string. The other answer is using a string. I wouldn't go as far as to say its wrong, because it depends on what variables you have floating around in the rest of your code, but it certainly would introduce a dependency on that variable existing at creation time, that the string version doesn't have.

Comment: Design time dependency. You have a point there. I will not edit my answer - so, someone else can learn the difference between two answers. The above down vote should have been down vote  +  a comment. Now we have some!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add that module in the module you have to use the filter, for example, imagine you have an app module:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.filters'])
```

After that you will use it